# javascript - scrollToView(false) not working

Tags: javascript

I've try to make a div scroll to bottom on click:

```
export default function App() {
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log('onClick');
    const objDiv = document.getElementById('container');
    console.log('objDiv', objDiv);
    objDiv.scrollIntoView(false);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} id="container">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]
I've searched the internet, and they said the most modern way to do it is with scrollIntoView().
but it just won't working. I don't want to use jquery or any other thirdparty lib. just want native javascript way to do it.
can someone help?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you're trying to scroll `#container` into view, correct? And `#container` is the red block in the screenshot, correct? It already is in plain view when you open the page, what do you expect to happen? If you want the last `<h1>Hello World</h1>` to be scrolled into view, you'd have to address that element and not just it's container, I'd assume.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do ? This method enables to scroll and highlight an element of a list.
In your case, you want to highlight the div, it's not the usecase of this method.
Read this article which explains this method with a demo : https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-scrollintoview/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the bottom of the element, this is how you do it with JavaScript:

```
objDiv.scrollTo(0,objDiv.scrollHeight);
```

or

```
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

your `#container` is already into view,
try creating element that you want into the view

```
const objDiv = document.querySelector('div h1:last-child');
```

it will scroll to specific element that want, not the container.

also make sure you container has `'overflow-y'` : set to `scroll` or `auto`, while fixing the `height`.